# QGIS layers panel doesn't show symbology

Tags: qgis, postgis, layers, symbology, table-of-contents

In the layers panel, the symbology next to the layer name doesn't show.  Reinstalling QGIS has not fixed the problem.

[image]

These are PostGIS point layers that draw on the map perfectly fine. The symbology used to show in the layers panel, but then disappeared recently. They disappeared *before* updating QGIS to 3.4.11. I was hoping the update would fix it.

The crazy thing is sometimes the symbology will momentarily appear in the layer panel, but then it disappears if you toggle a layer on or off. It's behaving like there isn't enough room to draw the symbology next to the layer name.

Comment: More details please. Do those layers have symbology? Do they actually appear on your map? What file format (shapefile/geopackage/etc) and geometry type (polygon/line/point) are they? What version of QGIS?

Comment: These are PostGIS point layers that draw on the map perfectly fine.  The symbology used to show in the layers panel, but then disappeared recently.  QGIS version is 3.4.11

Comment: "disappeared recently"... Did this change after you updated QGIS?

Comment: They disappeared before updating QGIS.  I was hoping the update would fix it. The crazy thing is sometimes the symboloy will momentarily appear in the layer panel, but then it disappears if you toggle a layer on or off. It's behaving like there isn't enough room to draw the symbology next to the layer name.

Comment: I never use postgis layers and I've never experienced this issue, which makes me wonder if it's postgis-specific. I added the postgis tag and also edited the details you provided into the body of the question. It could still be a bug, but I recommend seeing what other GIS.se users have to say before submitting a [bug report](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues).

Comment: Hello, as i saw this post and had QGIS 3.4.6 /3.4.11 on my PC and PostGres 9.6. / postgis 2.2. I made a test and the symbology seems to work perfectly with a point layer in both QGIS.